# Symfony collection form : allow_add: false not working

Tags: javascript, symfony, collections, twig

I have a form that has a remove and add button which should only be seen by the admin , a normal user should be able to submit the form but not add/remove it.

What happens is I put the buttons to false , but they keep showing up on the form. does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

What I have so far in my twig file  tag:

```
    % block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.collection.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    {% include 'includes/form/courseConditionalFields.js.twig' with {'formId' : 'studant_coursebundle_coursespecific' } %}


    $('.classes').collection({
        init_with_n_elements: 1,
        allow_up: false,
        allow_down: false,
        allow_add: false,
        allow_delete: false,
    })


</script>
```

in the jquery.collection I have:

```
{% block studant_coursebundle_classes_widget %}
<div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell auto">
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
    {%  if(is_granted('role_superman')) %}
    <div class="shrink auto">
        <a href="#" class="collection-remove button" title="{{ "Delete question"|trans  }}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="collection-add button alert" title="{{ "Add question"|trans  }}"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
```